# How to reduce compile time for unit tests with visual studio and c#

Tags: c#, testing, performance, compilation

I am working on a c# project and am having an issue with running my unit tests.  Specifically it seems that each time I modify one module in my source code, and then run my unit tests, Visual Studio rebuilds most if not all of my projects.

Any suggestions as to how to make this faster?

Comment: If you modify one project that a test project tests against, the test project needs to rebuild. If that test project references multiple projects I believe it will rebuild them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First modularize your tests.

Make sure that your libraries ore in the GAC.

Second run your code through ngen.exe (provided you don't changes your tests too much) to create a native image. Once you create a native image for an assembly, the runtime automatically uses that native image each time it runs the assembly.
Put the test code image in the GAC